# How to perform update on pg_index

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update the table pg_index ("disable" specific index) but I'm getting the error permission denied for relation pg_index. I already granted all on the table and I also tried to grant select,update,insert,delete.

I can't update but I can select.

```
db=> \z pg_catalog.pg_index;
                               Access privileges
Schema   |   Name   | Type  |    Access privileges    | Column privileges | 
Policies
------------+----------+-------+-------------------------+------------------
-+----------
pg_catalog | pg_index | table | =r/postgres            +|                   
|
        |          |       | report=arwdDxt/postgres |                   |
(1 row)
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to make sure that it woudnt use an index when I load the data so i set indisvalid=false on a specific index.

Comment: u can just `set enable_indexscan to off`

Comment: It wont change the settings only for the current session/ transaction ? I want to disable the index scan for a specific table , is there a better way ?

Comment: `set local` will change for transaction, just `set` or `set session` for session. of course you can disable it for all cluster (highly unadvisable)

Comment: Its part of a function which means : 1) I disable the index scan 2)I load the data 3)I enable the index

Comment: I want to disable it only for a speicifc table , is it possible ?

Comment: no - you can `off` before statement and `on` after - but it will be applied to all tables in statement.

Comment: I read that if i will change the column indisvalid from pg_index the index wont be used. Is it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update pg_index as superuser and you must grant permissions also as superuser if not.

But don't do this!

For a specific query you can disable usage of an index with `set enable_indexscan = off`.

For bulk loading data (and speeding it up) - do an `pg_dump -s` to backup the database schema including the indices. Then simply drop them, load your data and recreate them afterwards.

Comment: OK THANKS I WILL DROP THEM AND RECREATE THEM

Comment: Apart from that, also if you 'disable' the index it is invalid afterwards the bulk insert anyway and you need to rebuild it. 

Keep in mind if there are unique indices on your table you might need to solve any issues with duplicates when recreating that index.